# Remove '=' character from a string

Tags: javascript

I have a string as follows:

```
var string = "=09e8d76c-c54c-32e1-a98e-7e654d32ec1f";
```

How do I remove the '=' character from this? I've tried a couple of different ways but the '=' character seems to be causing a conflict

Comment: did you bother doing any research before posting this question?

Comment: You would not be assign string back to get the changed string.

Answer (score 1):

If it's always the first character then this will work...

```
var string = "=09e8d76c-c54c-32e1-a98e-7e654d32ec1f".substring(1);
```

If it's not definitely the first character then this will work...

```
var string = "=09e8d76c-c54c-32e1-a98e-7e654d32ec1f".replace("=", "");
```

If it's in there more than once then this will work...

```
var string = "=09e8d76c-c54c-32e1-a98e-7e654d32ec1f".split("=").join("");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)**:

> The replace() method returns a new string with some or all matches of
>   a pattern replaced by a replacement

```
string = string.replace('=','');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E8sc3/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple.

```
var string = "=09e8d76c-c54c-32e1-a98e-7e654d32ec1f";
string=string.replace('=','');
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the first character:

```
string = string.substring(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
var string = "=09e8d76c-c54c-32e1-a98e-7e654d32ec1f";
if(string.indexOf('=')>=0){ //check string contains =
   string = string.replace("=",'');
}
```